# CodeIgniter Database Connection Issue

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter, and I'm not able to use my database with it. I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/CodeIgniter-Preparing-Database-P162.html) exactly, but when I open in localhost I receive a 404 page.

Comment: please provide us with some more information. is the standard installation working? do you get the welcome page? because 404 should have nothing todo with the database...

Comment: 404 actually means your page doesn't exist. Make sure you typed the right address.

Comment: ya i got the welcome page and also i created a hello world programme which is also working

Comment: but when i tried with database 404 error occures plz if u r having a tutorial over this put it here

Comment: do you get a 404 only when the database library gets loaded? more info please...

Comment: Can you please post one sample of the controller code, and the url you are calling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up your application/config/database.

Here you need to add your information for your database.

```
$active_group = "default";
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['default']['username'] = "yourdbusername";
$db['default']['password'] = "password_for_db";
$db['default']['database'] = "name_of_db";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

Have you done it?

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting a 404, it may not be your database connection. Check your routing, and be sure that you are accessing a page that does indeed exist. If you're accessing a controller that loads a view, stop loading the view for now and test the connection directly from the controller - output "YES" if it is, and "NO" if anything else.

If your problem persists, double-check your database-connection configuration. Lastly, I would suggest you follow the documentation rather than another website when you are getting familiar with a framework. You can view the documentation for the Database class at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you try http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/employee/GetAll ?
Are you using CodeIgniter 2 ?