# codeigniter using Utility with inactive database

Tags: codeigniter

I use a model in codeigniter to switching between many databases in my script, and i want to use Utility class, when i use it it's deal with the database that is write as an active_group in database config file, Can i change it to deal with any other database inactive ?

Comment: @manix I tried to take a backup from a database not the same in the "active_group" variable in database config file

Answer (score 0):

I think that [how to use use multiple dbs ignoring active_group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113570/codeigniter-database-connection-issue?rq=1) is what you are looking for.